# Non-English Language Question Analyser

Tags: app, stackoverflow

This is a simple Bot which uses Stack Overflow public API and chat to continuously scan new questions and report in chat the ones which are most likely not written in English.

This project can be used for other purposes as well, simply by attaching different tracking logic as a new service. Currently, there are two active services:

- NELQA: Scans the question with simple regex rules to guess the language in which it was written. Reports all non-English language posts in chat.
- mysqli: Scans the question in search for PHP mysqli keywords.

This bot is not interactive and doesn't have a user interface, however it is possible to execute it from the command line. There exists an option to search existing Stack Overflow questions for matching keywords, but this feature is rather limited.

[GitHub page](https://github.com/kamil-tekiela/trackerBot)