# LegacyQuestions - Bringing back the old questions design

Tags: script, questions

### Preview

[image]

### What is LegacyQuestions? ([install](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/LegacyQuestions/latest.user.js))

LegacyQuestions brings back the old questions list design changed in a [recent update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually).

#### Changelog

- ###### v2.0

  - fixed [vertical list bug](https://stackapps.com/a/9654/76056), props to [Dani21 for the PR](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/pull/10)
- ###### v1.9

  - added support for user's answer & question list ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9373/76056))
  - fixed answer checkmark bug
- ###### v1.8

  - fixed watched icon hidden ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9593/76056))
- ###### v1.7

  - fixed statistic number clipping ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9319/76056))
  - optimization
- ###### v1.6

  - fixed broken statistics caused by structure change
- ###### v1.5

  - fixed 'votes' statistic color ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9308/76056))
- ###### v1.4

  - removed watched tag styling, fix alignment of post statistics ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9306/76056))
- ###### v1.3

  - fix misalignment issue ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9295/76056))
- ###### v1.2

  - make post statistics responsive ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9300/76056))
  - make match universal to include all question lists
- ###### v1.1

  - added bounty support ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9294/76056))
  - load new activity questions properly ([bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/9299/76056))

#### Browser Support

| IE | Chrome | Firefox | Safari | Edge | Opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔️ 6+ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ 5.1+ | ✔️ 12.1+ | ✔️ 12.1+ |

#### Additional Information

| #### License | #### Suggestions/Issues |
| --- | --- |
| [MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE) | Suggestions and issues should be raised as an answer in this post |

---

Languages/libraries used: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

Comment: Is it too much to ask for a bookmarklet version? Tamper and Greasemonkey don't work for me. I tried appending javascript: to the beginning but it isn't working. I think it might be the jQuery requirement?

Comment: @Firedestroyer Would something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/n8jLb3sh/) work?

Comment: It may be worth adding this script to [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372957), since this script is 100% essential.

Comment: Here's a updated bookmarklet version. I found [a great tool](https://chriszarate.github.io/bookmarkleter/) online to do it for me. Here's the bookmarkleted [code](https://bpa.st/MUFA).

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Votes/Answers/Views listed vertically.

I don't see that any changes to the home page just recently went live, so it may be something under the hood that has broken.

[image]

Comment: It looks like `.s-post-summary--stats` now includes `.s-post-summary` in the selector, which gives it more specificity. I tried adjusting the script to match that with `.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--stats`, and it seems to work. The change could be an accident on SE's side.

Comment: I'm using @AndrewMyers's fix: `sed 's/.s-post-summary--stats{/.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--stats{/g'`

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems some [recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el?cb=1) happened:

- There are ugly attention-snagging golden tags. Could you make them the normal blue instead? The eye is far enough, even though I don't think even that is useful.
- The "2votes" is squashed onto one line. It didn't use to be yesterday.

[image]

I am using chrome, version `1.3.1` of the auto-update version of your userscript.

Comment: I like the part where the bugged version of this script still looks better than the SE default.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I do not know if it's just me, but it seems to work amazingly well in a full-size browser window, but not when I make the browser (Chrome) fill only the right half of the screen:
[image]

This is still preferable to the new design of course, but it would be nice if you happened to fix this :)

Comment: Just noticed this and came here to post it.

Comment: @Spectric I just tried after your `status-complete` edit and can confirm it is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### "1 question with new activity" loads in incorrectly.

When a question is bumped to the top, you see this:

[image]

Loading the new question yields:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Watched tags icons are hidden and leave an empty space in front of the tag name

Userscript disabled:

[image: Userscript disabled]

Userscript enabled:

[image: Userscript enabled]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A bug that shows questions with thousands of views as `#` then on a new line `kviews`.

Shouldn't it be `#K Views`?

[image: Bug shows views in thousands as # kviews]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

This doesn't work for me, because jQuery isn't loaded when the script runs. (GreaseMonkey 4.11, Firefox 97.0b9). I had to add

```
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
```

to the userscript header.

Comment: GreaseMonkey is notoriously hard to be compatible. Are you bound to GreaseMonkey? If not, check if you can use / like TamperMonkey or ViolentMonkey.  Oth, if that line is all that is needed a specific GM4 version seems doable. But I'm not the maintainer, let's see what Spectric has to say.

Comment: I don't want to use TamperMonkey because it's not open-source. TIL about ViolentMonkey; I'll switch straight away!

Comment: Unfortunately it turns out this fix actually breaks https://chat.stackexchange.com, so you should just switch to ViolentMonkey.

Comment: ViolentMonkey works fine here. (Brave browser)

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

SE did an update to their website and that broke the way votes/answers/views look like (LegacyQuestions script):

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce this error anymore. Are you still experiencing that issue on your side?

Comment: @Spectric (I had to reinstall browser for personal issues and after that) I installed ViolentMonkey (in Firefox) like suggested in comments above here and it **works now**. I used GreaseMonkey previously. And, sorry but, I am too lazy to test if GreaseMonkey would work.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can this also be made to improve the user's questions and answers tabs e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/14251221/spectric?tab=answers

They now have way too much whitespace, they looked a lot better before. Unfortunately I don't have a screenshot of the before available.

Comment: Sorry for the delay :P