# Userstyles to (semi) revert the new Top Questions design

Tags: app, userstyle

These userstyles attempt to revert the unpopular changes introduced to the *Top Questions* pages.

See

- Announcement ~ [New post summary designs on greatest hits now, everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/158281)
- Source answer ~ [Custom Styles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375511/158281)
- Uploaded to Userstyles.org ~ https://userstyles.org/styles/227421/stack-overflow-front-page-grid-stats

```css
/** Container **/

.s-post-summary {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/** Stats grid **/

.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--stats {
  display: grid;
  width: unset;
  grid-template-areas:
    "score answers views"
    ". bounty ."
    ;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* change to 3 for views */
  column-gap: var(--s-post-summary-stats-gap);
  row-gap: var(--s-post-summary-stats-gap);
  align-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item,
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-answers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 60px;
}

/** State grid items **/

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item .s-post-summary--stats-item-number {
  font-size: larger;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: score;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: answers;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: views;
  display: none; /* remove for views */
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item.has-bounty {
  grid-area: bounty;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.s-post-summary--stats-item__emphasized {
  color: var(--fc-light);
}

/** Tags **/

.post-tag.s-tag__watched {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.post-tag.s-tag__watched:before {
  content: none;
}

/** Hide unwanted elements **/
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-accepted-answer .iconCheckmarkSm,
.s-post-summary--meta .s-avatar {
  display: none;
}
```

Apply to URLs matching regex `https://(.+\.)?stackoverflow.com/(questions)?(\?tab=.*)?`

[image: light mode]

[image: dark mode]

Caveats:

- Bounty badges aren't exactly where they used to be (though TBH it doesn't look too bad)
- I haven't changed the user and timestamp alignment (again, I think this looks ok)

Comment: Related: [Legacy Questions](https://stackapps.com/q/9293/34061)

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Only works on StackOverflow, not on other SE sites. E.g. check out https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Did you install from Userstyles.org? I think I hard-coded the URL. Looking at the HTML and CSS, it should work though

Comment: @PhilBrown Yep, from userstyles.org.

Comment: Hmm, I imagine detecting the views column is going to be tricky on non-english sites since I use the `title` attribute. Will have to think about this some more

Comment: @PhilBrown Mhm. I guess you could hardcode all translations (and their different forms).

Comment: I've fixed the URL to use a regex on userstyles.org now so should work on any *.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Views are not hidden when there's exactly one view:

[image: pic]

Comment: Oh wow, great catch. Will fix

Comment: I'm able to use `nth-child()` positions now so should be fixed