# Question and Answer Icon Annotations in Reputation History

Tags: script, reputation-audit

### Description

This UserScript makes it easier to differentiate post type in the reputation history ([/users/:user-id/username?tab=reputation](/users/current/?tab=reputation)) by adding Q and A icons as visual indicators.

Specifically, this script implements [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420255) by adding question and answer [Stacks icons](https://stackoverflow.design/product/resources/icons/#icon-set) before each link.

[image: Reputation page on Stack Overflow with Q and A Stacks Icons before each link]

This also functions as expected for reputation earned from suggested edits:

[image: Reputation page on Stack Overflow with Q and A Stacks Icons before each link. Approved suggested edits are also annotated with appropriate post types]

### Installation

1. Install a UserScript manager
2. Add the UserScript to your manager [install link](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/raw/main/QuestionAnswerIconsOnReputationHistory.user.js) ([GitHub Source](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/blob/main/QuestionAnswerIconsOnReputationHistory.user.js))

---

Future work: approved tag wiki suggested edits appear with a question indicator.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

It would be great if unlinked (deleted) post reputation changes (for example, the 1 reputation point refunds from downvoted answers that are subsequently deleted) had the icons as well. Currently, they do not have any (which is not a problem in my case, but may be for more active curators):

[image: a screenshot of two reputation change entries on answers with an upvote and the icon on the first one, and the removal refund on the second one due to deletion (the title of the latter appears unlinked)]

Relevant HTML markup for the unlinked item:

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="d-flex g4 p8 py2 md:p6 fw-wrap">
    <div class="d-flex g4 ai-center jc-end fs-caption wmn1 md:fd-row-reverse fc-black-500">
      <span title="post was removed">removed</span>
      <span class="s-badge baw0 bg-transparent fc-green-500">+1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex g4 fw-nowrap fl-grow1 break-word fs-body2 wmx100">
      <div class="flex--item as-center fs-body2 mt2 md:mt0">
        Typescript: Remove entries from tuple type
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So uh... interestingly this [does work if you have 10k+/can see the deleted post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnDwZ.png) because there is a link. What's the html on that for you?

Comment: @HenryEcker sure, added it to the answer :) I suspect that this is, indeed, a problem that is only happening because I don't have the 10K tools privilege yet.