# User style for mod strike

Tags: script, userstyle, stylish, moderation

Tested in Stylus on Firefox. Hides review queue, downvote, VTC, VTD, delete, undelete, and flag buttons/links.

```css
/* ==UserStyle==
@name           ModStrike
@namespace      github.com/openstyles/stylus
@version        1.0.0
@description    Hide Stack Exchange mod tools
@author         Someone
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document
    domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("stackoverflow.com"),
    domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("superuser.com"),
    domain("serverfault.com"), domain("stackapps.com")
{
    .js-vote-down-btn, .js-close-question-link, .js-flag-post-link,
    .js-comment-flag, .js-delete-post, #review-button,
    div#announcement-banner[data-campaign="2023-07-27.overflowai-announcement"]
    {
        display: none !important;
    } 
}
```

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/9739/stack-exchange-in-read-only-mode