# Helper module for SE API for Nushell

Tags: library

Following on from [Calling SE APIs with Nushell (basic overview)](https://stackapps.com/q/10180/83484), I have developed a helper module for calling SE API's in Nushell.  The library itself is short and included in the first answer.  Usage is documented here.

Note: Backoff support is built in.  If a `backoff` is received from the API, the method will pause *before* returning results.  Of course, this assumes that you are not running multiple API processes at the same time, which I'm told can be a problem with *any* usage of the API.

There are two methods:

- `callSeNetworkMethod <path/method> <params>` for network methods. Simple example:

  ```
  > $env.STACK_API_KEY="your_app's_key"

  > use <path_to>/seAPI *
  > callSeNetworkMethod "/sites" { pagesize: 1000 }
  # returns structured table of result to console
  > let sites = (callSeNetworkMethod "/sites" { pagesize: 1000 })
  > $sites.items | select name site_url | first 5
  ╭───┬─────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────╮
  │ # │        name         │             site_url              │
  ├───┼─────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────┤
  │ 0 │ Stack Overflow      │ https://stackoverflow.com         │
  │ 1 │ Server Fault        │ https://serverfault.com           │
  │ 2 │ Super User          │ https://superuser.com             │
  │ 3 │ Meta Stack Exchange │ https://meta.stackexchange.com    │
  │ 4 │ Web Applications    │ https://webapps.stackexchange.com │
  ╰───┴─────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────╯
  ```
- `callSeSiteMethod <path/method> <site> <params>` for per-site methods.  Simple example:

  ```
  # How many of the user's last 100 answers were accepted?
  > callSeSiteMethod "users/11810933/answers" | get items | where is_accepted | length
  52
  ```

  Parameterized user using variable interpolation:

  ```
  > let userId = 11810933
  > callSeSiteMethod $"users/($userId)/answers" | get items | where is_accepted | length
  52
  ```

Only the first argument is required.  If `site` is omitted for a site call, then `stackoverflow` is assumed.

`params` defaults to a sensible set of params, with:

- Your Stack API key if defined in the `STACK_API_KEY` environment variable.
- A pagesize of 100 records (max for most methods)

You do not need to specify these parameters when overriding the defaults - Your params will be merged into the set.

Example with multiple parameters:

```
# Find how many times "Jetpack Compose" has been mentioned in answers each year
> 2008..2023 | each {|year|
    let params = {                                                                                                                                                                                               
        filter: "!nNPvSNVZJS",
        pagesize: 0,
        q: $'is:a "Jetpack Compose" created:($year)'
    }
    {
        year: $year,
        totalAnswers: (callSeSiteMethod "/search/excerpts" "stackoverflow" $params).total
    }
  } | to md -p
```

| year | totalAnswers |
| --- | --- |
| 2008 | 0 |
| 2009 | 0 |
| 2010 | 0 |
| 2011 | 0 |
| 2012 | 0 |
| 2013 | 1 |
| 2014 | 1 |
| 2015 | 1 |
| 2016 | 1 |
| 2017 | 0 |
| 2018 | 2 |
| 2019 | 22 |
| 2020 | 70 |
| 2021 | 300 |
| 2022 | 474 |
| 2023 | 306 |

Answer (score 1):

`seAPI/mod.nu`:

```
def rootEndpoint [ ] {
    let key = (
        if 'STACK_API_KEY' in $env {
            $env.STACK_API_KEY
        } else {
            ""
        }
    )

    {
        scheme: "https",
        host: "api.stackexchange.com",
        params: {
            key: $key,
            pagesize: 100
        }
    }
}

export def callSeNetworkMethod [ path, params = {} ] {
    mut endpoint = (rootEndpoint | insert "path" $path)
    $endpoint.params = ($endpoint.params | merge $params) 
    callSeApiMethod $endpoint
}

export def callSeSiteMethod [ path, site = "stackoverflow", params:record = {} ] {
    mut endpoint = (rootEndpoint | insert "path" $path)
    # Merge site first so that it can be overridden by params
    $endpoint.params = ($endpoint.params | merge { site: $site } | merge $params)
    callSeApiMethod $endpoint
}

def callSeApiMethod [ endpoint: record ] {
    let res = (http get ($endpoint | url join))
    if "backoff" in $res {
        print "Backoff: " + $res.backoff
        sleep ( $"($res.backoff)sec" | into duration )
    }

    $res
}
```